# File change detection tool to find lines of code added, removed, or changed in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a tool that connects to hundreds of devices across multiple locations that each use JavaScript to format messages to be sent to our service. I can call each device and have it return its script to me, which I then compare to a baseline (golden) script that should be what is used.

What I am looking for is a way to streamline the comparison and enrich the output of each audit. This is currently handled with code commits in GIT or with online script comparison tools, but I need to automate this with Python to hand over to another team to implement and own. Currently, I am using ndiff from difflib to identify line numbers that are not what is expected. I am seeking advice on how to enhance this to create better visibility into exactly what was changed with each system.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Also, I am writing this tool in Python 3.11, but the team I am handing it over to is limited to Python 2.7 (Jython) as it will be part of our Inductive Automation Ignition SCADA software. We will not have a UI like https://onlinetextcompare.com/js; instead, we will automate an email to the vendor to denote all issues.

Example Baseline:

```
// Baseline v1.0
// Created on 02/20/2016
{
    console.log("The current datetime: " + new Date().toISOString());
    var x = 5;
    console.warn("The value of x: " + x);
}
```

Example Returned Script:

```
// Baseline v1.1
// Created on 02/25/2016
{
    var x = 10;
    console.log("Datetime: " + new Date().toISOString());
    console.log("Fun stuff");
}
```

Output:

Added:

```
console.log("Fun stuff");
```

Removed:

```
console.warn("The value of x: " + x);
```

Changed:

```
// Baseline v1.0 --> // Baseline v1.1
Created on 02/20/2016 --> Created on 02/25/2016
var x = 5; --> var x = 10;
```

Comment: When you detect a problem with ndiff, you could clone a copy of the golden git repo then add the monitored file(s). Now you have all of the git tools available on this clone. Since you need to backport to jython, keeping the python simple and calling external tools is a benefit.